# Should i use a three way pivot table and how to fetch with Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to get my Eloquent models to work. My current database is like this:

[image]

The tricky part is that for a given Environment and Project, there can be multiple Accesses. So it is possible i have something like this:

[image: access datatabase]

Note that both rows has the same environment_id and project_id.

**Question 1 :** Is my database well designed? Or should i have created a three-way pivot table (id, project_id, environment_id, access_id) ?

**Question 2 :** How can i fetch all environments associated with a project in my Project model? Right now it looks like this:

```
class Project extends Model
{    

    public function accesses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Access', 'project_id');
    }


    public function environments(){
      // The missing part i can't get to work :(
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest you add a separete table for the access, that way you won't have duplicate data or problems with password resets.
If you just want all the environments linked to a project you want a many to many or one to many relation with pivot.

```
public function environments()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('environment', 'environment_project');
     // the first argument is the model you link to, the second the pivot table
    }
```

models:

```
Environment: id, name

Project: id, name

Environment_project:id, environment_id, project_id, access_id

Access: id, username, password
```

edit, access on pivot

```
public function environments()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('environment', 'environment_project')->withPivot('username', 'password');
     //now you can do project::find(1)->environments->pivot->username
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This application is just to store credentials, like a password manager. I won't use it for authentification, sor there will be no such thing as password resets.
I think i will add a `Environment_project` like you said. Thank you

Comment: if the username / password combi is specific to the project<->environment then you don' t need a separate access table and could just leave it on the pivot table

Comment: @pelomedusa i added the relationship function if you want to access data on the pivot table as seen on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many under the header `Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns`

Comment: from what i understand, then i could juste use my "access" table as a pivot, and leave it as was initially? Then i guess i would use something like.
`$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Environment', 'accesses')`
Did i miss something?

Comment: sounds about right yes. shouldn't it be access tho? or is the table called accesses?

Comment: Yes the table is called accesses. It doesnt work, i get an empty result

Comment: if there should be a connection it could be that laravel is looking for the wrong keys. first make sure that there is an envirement linked to the project you have selected. second try this `return $this->belongsToManyApp\Models\Environment', 'accesses', 'project_id', 'environment_id');` this sets the keys on the pivot table for laravel

Comment: It works! I was using the mongodb adaptation `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`, i think it's a bug of the reimplementation of belongToMany. Using MySQL Eloquent models, it works. Sorry for bothering you.